# CalendarExtender how to show only a few days

Tags: javascript, asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

How do I make the calendarextender show just a few days? The other days must appear disabled.

Like for example, theater booking websites.

Thanks,

Comment: [I don't think that it is supported in the current version of the Toolkit to restrict selectable dates.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5608560/284240)

Comment: After much research it is also what I think.

Comment: You had realized that i've posted a link? ;-)